# How to enable Telerik RadGrid UI setting

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, telerik

I have a C# project that is attached to a sql database. I needed some advance settings in GridView so my friend helped me use a Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadGridView which is good for my purpose but for some reason while it works perfectly on my friend's system, it seems to be missing some things in mine. I have Telerik UI for WinForms Q3 2015 SP1 installed on my system but I cannot "select" the gridview in my form and the "UI setting" doesn't appear on the top right of the gridview. If I need to see the properties of the view I have to choose it from the above list in properties tab. I can use a few of the options in the properties tab to edit the GridView UI (like for example column ) but it does not have everything I need. Can anyone help me about this? Why my GridView is disabled while it works perfectly in my friend's system?

Comment: Do you have a license for it?

Comment: If you are asking if it is a cracked version, no. It is a retail copy. I have no idea if my friend's was cracked or not

Comment: FYI the license does not permit sich passing of the software from one friend to another. It is per seat based, so you are probably using it illegally and you may want to contact Telerik how to resolve this. Anyway, see my post below for an answer to your question.

Comment: Hey. I am aware of THAT. I didn't mean my friend pass the "software" to me! He just used the instance on my project and then I got the software myself and installed it on my system. That's why I cannot figure out why it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find an answer to your question: [RadControls for WinForms are not loaded at design-time](http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/winforms/details/radcontrols-for-winforms-are-not-loaded-at-design-time)